# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre usar = o == en una comparación de texto en Bash? ¿Cuál debería usar?

Tags: bash, condiciones, script

Estos dos códigos funcionan:

```
if [ $animal = "perro" ]; then
    echo "El animal es un perro"
else
    echo "Se desconoce el animal"
fi
```

Y:

```
if [ $animal == "perro" ]; then
    ...
```

En uno usé `=` y en el otro `==` para hacer una comparación en un script de Bash.

¿Cuál debería usar? ¿El igual normal ' = ' o el doble igual ' == ' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haciéndo énfasis en la respuesta de @fedorqui [sobre *==*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions): **Es un bashismo**.

Es decir, es un slang muy propio de *bash* y de otra shell que quiera adoptarlo; pero **no hay un consenso**. **No está en el estándar POSIX**.

Lo cual dice que **puede no ser compatible entre shells que sigan el estándar POSIX**.

Complementando la respuesta de @fedorqui pongo un ejemplo.

Usemos `bash`, `zsh`, o `tcsh`:

```
$ bash -c '[ "a" == "a" ] && echo si || echo no'
si
```

Todo luce bien.

Ahora usemos otra shell como `dash`:

```
$ dash -c '[ "a" == "a" ] && echo si || echo no'
dash: 1: [: a: unexpected operator
no
```

Esto sucede porque a pesar de que bash es compatible con el token *==*, no es así en `dash` (¡Que suele ser el alias por defecto de `sh`!).

Y esto no para. Continuemos con la [shell exótica `fish`](https://fishshell.com):

```
$ fish -c '[ "a" == "a" ] && echo si || echo no'
[: unexpected argument at index 2: '=='
Standard input (line 1):
[ "a" == "a" ] && echo si || echo no
^
no
```

Y tenemos un error.

Aunque de todas maneras, `fish` es muy exótico, i.e., poco POSIX.

Por último, intentemos con `ash`:

```
$ ash -c '[ "a" == "a" ] && echo si || echo no'
ash: 1: [: a: unexpected operator
no
```

Como pudimos ver, usamos 3 shells donde el token *==* no es reconocido.

Answer (score 2):

Si estás usando Bash, ambas son válidas: POSIX tiene definido `=` como el estándar. Bash sigue este estándar, pero también incorpora `==`.

Por tanto, si quieres usar un código lo más versátil posible, usa `=`. Si por el contrario sabes que solamente correrá en Bash, puedes usar `==`.